# SQL; OR syntax not working

Tags: php, mysql

Alright So I have a sql command. Please see below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders 
        WHERE loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times 
        AND name LIKE :keyword OR odryname LIKE :keyword OR pdryname LIKE :keyword 
        OR jlc LIKE :keyword OR odrphone LIKE :keyword 
        OR biid LIKE :keyword OR dstreet LIKE :keyword ";
$q=$con->prepare($sql);
$q->bindvalue(":keyword", "%".$keyword."%");
```

So the command works until the first OR in it... It will check if the logged time is what I put in and the NAME is like the keyword..

The only part of the command that should be constant is `WHERE loggedtime = :time` the rest should be based on if the keyword matches... But it should not display any results at all if the time on that order is incorrect.

Comment: When you combine AND and OR in the same query, make sure you understand the rules for evaluating these, and apply brackets where appropriate.... LIKES (WHISKY OR PIZZA) AND CRICKET is not the same as LIKES WHISKY OR (PIZZA AND CRICKET)

Comment: ...or better yet. To make things clearer in general, I would suggest always parenthesizing conditions containing AND & OR; even if you know the order of evaluation: it is one less thing for your mind to parse when reading, and when you come back to it later, it is easier to remember/read your intent.

Comment: @MarkBaker That worked, I understand using brackets now for that. Thank you. Please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

put this into ()  `loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times` so your query should be :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE (loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times) 
AND name LIKE :keyword OR odryname LIKE :keyword OR pdryname LIKE :keyword 
OR jlc LIKE :keyword OR odrphone LIKE :keyword 
OR biid LIKE :keyword OR dstreet LIKE :keyword ";
```

Answer (score 1):

As you specified, there are two main conditions which are regarded to `logged time` and other fields that compare with `keyword`.
 You need to group logically related operators with braces. 
When combining these conditions(*AND* condition and *OR* condition ), it is important to use round brackets so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition. 
Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders 
        WHERE loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times 
        AND (name LIKE :keyword OR odryname LIKE :keyword OR pdryname LIKE :keyword 
        OR jlc LIKE :keyword OR odrphone LIKE :keyword 
        OR biid LIKE :keyword OR dstreet LIKE :keyword) ";
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical `AND` operator has a higher precedence than the logical `OR`. This is documented in detail in [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).

So without explicit braces, your current statement actually reads like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
    WHERE (loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times 
    AND name LIKE :keyword) OR odryname LIKE :keyword OR pdryname LIKE :keyword 
    OR jlc LIKE :keyword OR odrphone LIKE :keyword 
    OR biid LIKE :keyword OR dstreet LIKE :keyword
```

As `OR` has a lower precedence than `AND`, you'll need braces to group all the `OR`ed conditions together:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
    WHERE loggedtime BETWEEN :time AND :times 
    AND (name LIKE :keyword OR odryname LIKE :keyword OR pdryname LIKE :keyword 
    OR jlc LIKE :keyword OR odrphone LIKE :keyword 
    OR biid LIKE :keyword OR dstreet LIKE :keyword)
```